# How to insert values to SQLite on button click (WPF)

Tags: c#, database, wpf, sqlite

I'm trying to insert values on SQLite database with code like this:

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     string database_connection = "Data Source=database.db;Version=3;";
     SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(database_connection);
     connection.Open();

     string query = String.Format("INSERT INTO `database`.`airports`(`id`, `airportName`, `airportCity`, `active`) VALUES ('"+txtAirportId+"','"+txtAirportName+"','"+txtAirportCity+"','"+1+"')");
     SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(query, connection);
     SQLiteDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(command);
     connection.Close();

     txtAirportId.Clear();
     txtAirportName.Clear();
     txtAirportCity.Clear();

}
```

And this is xaml code:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgAirports" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="100" Width="272" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="false" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Шифра" Binding="{Binding Path = id}" Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Назив" Binding="{Binding Path = airportName}"  Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Град" Binding="{Binding Path = airportCity}" Width="*"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

        <Label x:Name="lblAirportId" Content="ИД" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="123,115,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtAirportId" Text="{Binding ElementName=dgAirports, Path=SelectedValue.id}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="157,115,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="125"/>

        <Label x:Name="lblAirportName" Content="Назив" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="109,142,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtAirportName" Text="{Binding ElementName=dgAirports, Path=SelectedValue.airportName}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="157,143,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="125"/>

        <Label x:Name="lblAirportCity" Content="Град" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="115,168,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtAirportCity" Text="{Binding ElementName=dgAirports, Path=SelectedValue.airportCity}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="157,171,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="125"/>


        <Button x:Name="btnShow" Content="Прикажи" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,115,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btnShow_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnAdd" Content="Додај" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,142,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btnAdd_Click"/>
    </Grid>
```

So when I click on `btnAdd` nothing happening but I don't get any errors. So, what I'm missing and how to insert that values to 'airports' table?

Comment: you created a `command` but didn't execute/run it

Comment: Never, ever glue data into a string to make a query - especially with SQLite.  Always use SQL Parameters.

Comment: @ASh But almost on the same way I have a button click action to fill DataGrid from database. Of course `string query` is diferent, but what I'm missing right now? How to execute it?

Comment: Where does \`database\`.\`airports\` come from? (Use double quotes for identifiers if you feel the need to quote them, btw: `"database"."airports"`) Your example doesn't [ATTACH](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) any database with a `"database"` schema name (And it's a bad name to use, since DATABASE is a keyword and using it as an identifier means you have to quote it, which looks ugly)

Answer (score -1):

Just change your function like this:

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string database_connection = "Data Source=database.db;Version=3;";
    SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(database_connection);
    connection.Open();

    string query = String.Format($"INSERT INTO `database`.`airports`(`id`, `airportName`, `airportCity`, `active`) VALUES ('{txtAirportId }','{txtAirportName }','{txtAirportCity}','1')");
    SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(query, connection);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    txtAirportId.Clear();
    txtAirportName.Clear();
    txtAirportCity.Clear();
}
```

BTW: your code still will be not good. At least you will have SQL Injection vulnerability if you just contact string. Use Parameters or read about [Entity Framework Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/) Technology.

Comment: Now i get this error: An unhandled exception of type 'Finisar.SQLite.SQLiteException' occurred in SQLite.NET.dll on `command.ExecuteNonQuery();` line... Is there any way to execute query without creating separated function for executing?

Comment: post here full exception message pelase

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'Finisar.SQLite.SQLiteException' occurred in SQLite.NET.dll

Additional information: no such table: database.airports

Even if there is database called 'database' and table called 'airports', obvious.

Comment: it's related to your database schema and, probably, connection access right. Make sure that you have table `airports` in you database `database` (very wired name), and your connection have rights to write  into this table.